# jQuery UI Accordion Embedded Form Rename Header

Tags: jquery-ui, forms, accordion

I want to embed a form in my accordion.  I want a user to be able to edit the contents of the accordion.  Things work fine for the content section of the accordion, but when I try to edit the header of the accordion I can't insert spaces (and when I do press space the currently selected content panel collapses).  I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that the header is defined by a `<a></a>` block, but I can't think why pressing space bar matters or how to get around the issue.

```
function makeAccordion(){
            var stop = false;
            $("#accordion h3").click(function(event){
                if (stop) {
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    event.preventDefault();
                    stop = false;

                }
            });
            $("#accordion").accordion({
                header: "h3"
            }).sortable({
                axis: "y",
                handle: "h3",
                stop: function(event, ui){
                    stop = true;
                }
            });
        }

<body>
    <div id="accordion">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div id ="1">
                <h3 id ="h3_1"><a href="#">Step Name: <input type="text" name="stepName"></a></h3>
                <div id ="content_1">
                    Step: <input type="text" name="content">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution, but I'm not sure of the consequences.

In jquery.ui.accordion.js:

```
_keydown: function( event ) {
    if ( this.options.disabled || event.altKey || event.ctrlKey ) {
        return;
    }

    var keyCode = $.ui.keyCode,
        length = this.headers.length,
        currentIndex = this.headers.index( event.target ),
        toFocus = false;

    switch ( event.keyCode ) {
        case keyCode.RIGHT:
        case keyCode.DOWN:
            toFocus = this.headers[ ( currentIndex + 1 ) % length ];
            break;
        case keyCode.LEFT:
        case keyCode.UP:
            toFocus = this.headers[ ( currentIndex - 1 + length ) % length ];
            break;
        case keyCode.SPACE:
        case keyCode.ENTER:
            this._clickHandler( { target: event.target }, event.target );
            event.preventDefault();
    }

    if ( toFocus ) {
        $( event.target ).attr( "tabIndex", -1 );
        $( toFocus ).attr( "tabIndex", 0 );
        toFocus.focus();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
},
```

Notice the "fall through" from space to enter.  I added a break:

```
_keydown: function( event ) {
    if ( this.options.disabled || event.altKey || event.ctrlKey ) {
        return;
    }

    var keyCode = $.ui.keyCode,
        length = this.headers.length,
        currentIndex = this.headers.index( event.target ),
        toFocus = false;

    switch ( event.keyCode ) {
        case keyCode.RIGHT:
        case keyCode.DOWN:
            toFocus = this.headers[ ( currentIndex + 1 ) % length ];
            break;
        case keyCode.LEFT:
        case keyCode.UP:
            toFocus = this.headers[ ( currentIndex - 1 + length ) % length ];
            break;
        case keyCode.SPACE:
            break;
        case keyCode.ENTER:
            this._clickHandler( { target: event.target }, event.target );
            event.preventDefault();
    }

    if ( toFocus ) {
        $( event.target ).attr( "tabIndex", -1 );
        $( toFocus ).attr( "tabIndex", 0 );
        toFocus.focus();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
},
```

You still get the closing behavior on pressing "enter", so feel free to break there if necessary as well.  I think the problem is in

```
this._clickHandler( { target: event.target }, event.target );
```

but I didn't see it on my first read through.  This edit works for me.

Hope that helps